# Automatically close Chrome or Firefox like IE when ending a Visual Studio debugging session

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, firefox, integration, visual-studio-2017

When I debug a web project in Visual Studio in Internet Explorer, the browser closes automatically when I end the debug session. Similarly, when I end the browser first, so ends the debug session. I understand that IE has special integration with Visual Studio.

My question is: Can I enable such integration on Chrome and Firefox, perhaps with a browser or Visual Studio extension?

My research: I've searched online for "firefox visual studio integration", "close debug chrome visual studio" but nothing related appeared.
Searches for "chrome" or "firefox" in the Visual Studio Extension Manager yield no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2017, Chrome debugging is fully supported.
As of this writing, Firefox and Edge is [coming later](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/) (Yes, Microsoft added support for Google Chrome before their own Edge browser).

[image]

Comment: How do I enable this for Chrome. Works on one of my PCs but not on another both running Win 10 VS 2107 latest

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of googling reveals that right clicking on your .apspx file, clicking "Browse with ...", selecting Chrome or Firefox, and then clicking "Set as Default" will set the browser of your choice to your default debugging browser, which I assume opens and closes along with the debug session. I see you tagged this as a Visual  Studio 2010 question, but I also read that in Visual Studio 2012 you can choose which browser you want to debug with from the dropdown box over the code editor.